# Graph and MST, Some Facts and Validity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, minimum-spanning-tree

My notes tell me that the **first** and **last** is false. I need some idea of how to understand the validity of these sentences in a more simple and concise manner.

Suppose M is an MST ([minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree)) of the Weighted Graph - GR.

1. Let A be a vertex of GR then M-{A} is also MST of GR-{A}.
2. Let A  be a leaf of M then M-{A} is also MST of GR-{A}.
3. If e is a edge of M then (M-{e}) is a forest of M1 and M2 trees such that for M_i, i=1,2 is a MST of Induced Graph GR on vertexes T_i.

Comment: I believe 1. is quite simple: If you remove a node A from a graph then the MST is not necessarily the original MST without this node A. -> Removing the node A from the graph might "break" it into two isolated graphs. Resp. the MST might break into two MSTs. (to give one counter example)

Comment: Since we know (2) is true, then we kinda assume that in (1) A is not a leaf. Since it's in a tree, removing it will create a forest, not a tree. Does that help with (1) ?

Comment: @shapiroyaacov sure, I need a little example or logic especially for (3). sure it's solve  my doubt.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65212172/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133001/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65102458/781723, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3930612/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Let A be a vertex of GR, then M-{A} is also MST of GR-{A}.

This is false.

If A is not a leaf, then M-{A} is not a connected graph, and so it cannot be a MST.

In more detail: A has at least two neighbors, and the single path (MST property) that exists between two of them includes A. If A is removed, then there is no more path between those two other vertices.

> 2. Let A be a leaf of M, then M-{A} is also MST of GR-{A}.

This is true.

As A is a leaf, M-{A} is a connected graph, and has one fewer edge than M: it does not have the edge *e* that connects with A in M.

Now assume that M-{A} is not a MST of GR-{A}. We know that M-{A} is a connected graph, and has no cycles -- otherwise M would not be an MST. So if it is not an MST, it must be that its weight is not minimised. Then there is a different graph P that *is* a MST of GR-{A}. But then P+e would have less total weight than M, but still be a spanning tree of GR. So then M could not have been a MST of GR. This is a contradiction, and so the original statement is true.

> 3. If e is a edge of M then M-{e} is a forest of M<sub>1</sub> and M<sub>2</sub> trees such that for M<sub>i</sub>, i=1,2 is a MST of the induced graph GR on vertexes T<sub>i</sub>.

This is true. Your notes are wrong on this one.

Let's assume that M<sub>i</sub> (for either i=1,2) is not a MST of the induced graph on vertexes T<sub>i</sub>. We know that M<sub>i</sub> is not disconnected (the removal of *e* creates exactly 2 connected graphs), and that it has no cycles (otherwise M would have had those as well). So if it is not a MST, then the reason would be that its weight is not minimised, and another graph P<sub>i</sub> *is* a MST on that induced graph, and has less total weight than M<sub>i</sub>.

If you would then reintroduce the edge *e*, and so connect P<sub>i</sub> with M<sub>3-i</sub>, we would have a spanning tree for GR which would have less weight than M, and so M is not a MST. This is again a contradiction and so the original statement is true.

Comment: @BettyAndersson, thanks. Any non-trivial graph would be a good example. Take the one depicted [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d2/Minimum_spanning_tree.svg/600px-Minimum_spanning_tree.svg.png). Choose an edge to remove, for instance the one in the center with weight 8. Then you have two graphs, and each is an MST on the vertices it connects (i.e. on the "induced" graph that doesn't include the "light" colored edges that would connect the two MSTs).